# Using document to handle all events in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is it a good idea to manage all click events under the document element?  The DOM is being constantly manipulated, so instead of constantly registering new events for each newly created DOM element, can't I just assign one event handler on the document element?  For example:

```
document.onclick = function(event) {
  switch(event.target.id) {
    case 'someid':
      // SOME ACTION
      break;
    case 'someotherid':
      // SOME OTHER ACTION
      break;
    default:
      // A CLICK WITH NO ACTION
  }
};
```

Comment: Yes, this is called event delegation. However, I’d use a different parent element for the individual elements: it’s bad practice to have a function do all kinds of different things. Separate any two event listeners into two different functions if they behave totally different.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know what that was called.  So, essentially I can register events to each of the main parent elements, and manage the application's events that way, right?  But you are saying one parent should have a separate click event, mouseover event, etc. ?

Comment: Delegate to the closest possible ancestor, not `document`

Comment: yes, but `id` might be a bit constraining, it would be better to use a fancy sub-selector... one way is to push all your dom events into an EventEmitter and subscribe to types with code like you have (without event assignment), and that allows many functions to be added/removed...

Answer (score 2):

Yes. This pattern is called event delegation, you can find a [great article](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) on the blog of [David Walsh](https://davidwalsh.name/)

You should also take a look at the Element matches / matchesSelector API

-https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/matches

-https://davidwalsh.name/element-matches-selector

Comment: Nice!  Thanks for the info on matches.  That will make it easier and neater to delegate events by matching id, class, or attrib data.  I'll definitely have to use that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, but it's not as efficient as binding events to specific elements. It means your function will run if someone clicks in a place that isn't mentioned in any of your cases. And even if it is, it will have to search sequentially through your cases until it finds the right one.

A somewhat better way to do it is to use an object keyed off the IDs.

```
var handlers = {
    "someid": function(event) { // some action
    },
    "someotherid": function(event) { // some other action
    },
    ...
}

document.onclick = function(event) {
    if (handlers[event.target.id]) {
        handlers[event.target.id](event);
    } else {
        // default action
    }
}
```

This addresses the sequential searching problem, but it still runs when someone clicks on an unbound element. This probably isn't much of an issue for clicks, but imagine doing the same thing for mouse movement events, which occur almost constantly.

Also, this doesn't generalize easily to binding handlers to classes or more complicated selectors.

What you're doing is similar to how jQuery implements `.on()` event binding, when you write:

```
$(document).on("click", "someSelector", handlerFunction);
```

This form is generally only used when specifically needed, which is when the elements that match the selector are created dynamically -- it allows you to define the handler once, not add and remove it as elements change.  But for static elements, we generally use the simpler

```
$("selector").on("click", handlerFunction);
```

because then the browser takes care of running the handler only when one of the selected elements is clicked.

Comment: Yes, that takes care of the searching, but like you said won't work for complicated selectors.